# linux / mac command line autocomplete (google search style)

Tags: linux, macos, autocomplete

Anybody know a good way to get my command line in Linux or Mac to behave similar to that of google autocomplete? http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106230

I feel like I've seen this before but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the features in [fish 2.0](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/).

[image]

You have to build it from source (`brew install fish` is an older version).

```
git clone git://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell
cd fish-shell
xcodebuild install
sudo ditto /tmp/fish.dst /
/usr/local/bin/fish
```

Comment: this is frickin awesome... can't wait to try it!